# Had gotten paid / were paid

Tags: grammar

Which one of these two is correct:

> 1. If I **had gotten paid** we could have traveled together.
> 2. If I **were paid** we could have traveled together.

Comment: Both work and mean different things, so what's the context? In BrE *gotten* would be *got*, and *traveled* would be *travelled*.

Comment: @userr2684291 my question is: which one should I use: 1: had gotten or were paid!?

Comment: Well, what are you trying to say? What's the context in which you'd like to say this?

Comment: okay for example I’m talking to my friend who just came back from traveling around the world and I wanna tell him that if I...(here which one of two should be placed?)...I could have traveled with him together!

Comment: Okay, here's the gag: *if I had gotten paid* refers to some unreal situation in the past where you didn't get paid, while *if I were paid* (refers to an unreal situation in the present and) first assumes that you work for free and don't get paid, and then says: *if that were not true...*

Comment: Please bear in mind that: **If I had gotten paid (AmE)** and **If I had got paid (BrE)** both mean the same thing as **If I had been paid**. Base forms: **to get paid** and **to be paid**. They mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how my American English ear interprets those combinations of tenses:

> If I had gotten paid, we could have traveled together.

**I received no pay for the work I did**. We *were* thus unable to travel together or We *are* thus unable to travel together. (That's not a paraphrase but a restatement of the scenario.)

> If I were paid we could have traveled together.

**I am receiving no pay for the work I do**. If I did receive money for this work, we would have been able to travel together or we would be able to travel together.

It is not really possible to know in either case whether the speaker is referring to a past missed opportunity or a future missed opportunity, since **could have traveled** here refers to traveling that did not take place. It is merely a conditional result of a condition that was never realized.

If you wanted to say that a trip now or in the future would be possible:

> If I had gotten paid, **we could travel together**.
>
> If I were paid, **we could travel together**.